# Is setTimeout required?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, settimeout

I have a question to async, await and setTimeout().
I thought, I use asynchron functions for slow processes. So I tried it with a large loop. On my Computer, it needs few seconds to run the following code:

```
function slowFunction() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            for (let i = 0; i < 4000000000; i++) {};
            resolve('Ready at ' + new Date().toLocaleTimeString('de'));
        }, 0);
    });
};


console.log('Start: ' + new Date().toLocaleTimeString('de'));

(async () => {
    console.log('Call slow function.');
    console.log(await slowFunction());
})();

console.log('There is no need to wait for the slow function: ' + new Date().toLocaleTimeString('de'));
```

The output is:

```
Start: 16:39:20
Call slow function.
There is no need to wait for the slow function: 16:39:20
Ready at 16:39:23
```

And now the question: What is the difference to the next code:

```
function slowFunction() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        for (let i = 0; i < 4000000000; i++) {};
        resolve('Ready at ' + new Date().toLocaleTimeString('de'));
    });
};

console.log('Start: ' + new Date().toLocaleTimeString('de'));

(async () => {
    console.log('Call slow function.');
    console.log(await slowFunction());
})();

console.log('There is no need to wait for the slow function: ' + new Date().toLocaleTimeString('de'));
```

The output is:

```
Start: 16:39:20
Call slow function.
There is no need to wait for the slow function: 16:39:23
Ready at 16:39:23
```

By the first example, it looks like asynchron. By the second example, the function wait for the end of loop.

Do I have to use setTimeout or do I have an error in the code or am I getting it wrong? I both cases, the resolve statment is behind the large loop.

The most examples for async and await used setTimeout, but I think, it's just to simulate a break.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Best greets
Pascal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### TL:DR

Promises and `async` functions don't offload your code to another thread. If you want to move that long-running process off the main thread, on browsers look at [web workers](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/), and on Node.js look at [child processes](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html).

### Details

Promises and `async` functions (which are just a syntax for creating and consuming promises) don't move your processing to any other thread, it still happens on the same thread you start the process on. The **only** thing they do is ensure that `then` and `catch` callbacks are called asynchronously. They don't make your code asynchronous (other than that one thing, ensuring the callbacks happen asynchronously).

So your first block using `setTimeout` just sets a timeout, returns a promise, and then when the timeout expires it blocks the main thread while your slow-running process executes. This just changes when the blocking happens a little bit, it doesn't change the fact of the blocking.

You can see that effect here, notice how the counter pauses when the long-running process occurs:

```js
function slowFunction() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const stop = Date.now() + 2000;
      while (Date.now() < stop) {
        // busy wait (obviously, never really do this)
      }
    }, 1000);
  });
};

console.log("before slowFunction");
slowFunction()
  .then(() => {
    console.log("then handler on slowFunction's promise");
  })
  .catch(console.error);
console.log("after slowFunction");

let counter = 0;
const timer = setInterval(() => {
  console.log(++counter);
}, 100);
setTimeout(() => {
  clearInterval(timer);
  console.log("done");
}, 3000);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Your second block not using `setTimeout` just blocks right away, because the promise executor function (the function you pass `new Promise`) runs immediately and synchronously, and you're not doing anything to make it asynchronous.

You can see that here; the counter pauses right away, not later:

```js
function slowFunction() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const stop = Date.now() + 2000;
    while (Date.now() < stop) {
      // busy wait (obviously, never really do this)
    }
  });
};

console.log("before slowFunction");
slowFunction()
  .then(() => {
    console.log("then handler on slowFunction's promise");
  })
  .catch(console.error);
console.log("after slowFunction");

let counter = 0;
const timer = setInterval(() => {
  console.log(++counter);
}, 100);
setTimeout(() => {
  clearInterval(timer);
  console.log("done");
}, 3000);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

We don't even see the *before slowFunction* log appear until after the long-running code has finished, because the browser never got a chance to repaint, we had the thread hogged.

Regarding `async` functions: The code in an `async` function *starts out* synchronous, and is synchronous until the first `await` (or other construct, such as `setTimeout`, that schedules things to execute later). Only the code after that is asynchronous (because it had to wait).

Here's an example demonstrating that:

```js
async function foo() {
  console.log("before await");
  await Promise.resolve();
  console.log("after await");
}

console.log("before foo");
foo()
  .then(() => {
    console.log("then handler on foo's promise");
  })
  .catch(console.error);
console.log("after foo");
```

Here's the output of that:

```
before foo
before await
after foo
after await
then handler on foo's promise
```

Notice how *before await* occurs before *after foo*; it's synchronous with the call to `foo`. But then *after await* doesn't occur until later (because `await Promise.resolve()` has to make the code following it occur asynchronously; it's syntactic sugar for `then`, which promises not to call its handler synchronously even if the promise is already resolved).

Comment: Thanks for your fast and detailed reply. Now I understand the effect of async functions better. And I will read the part about the child processes. Thank you for the link.

I wish you a great weekend!

Comment: hi @T.J. Crowder +1 , Right on the first `await` encountered, will all the remaining code of the function execute asynchronously (even though there may no longer be `await`s), i.e., does a single `await` "**doom**" all the remaining code of the function to execute asynchronously?

Comment: In other words, can an `async` function "**toggle**" between being synchronous and asynchronous? @T.J. Crowder

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that this is completely synchronous code:

```
return new Promise(resolve => {
    for (let i = 0; i < 4000000000; i++) {};
    resolve('Ready at ' + new Date().toLocaleTimeString('de'));
});
```

This statement will block the JavaScript thread and force it to wait until all of those 4 billion iterations have taken place. *Then* it will move on to the next statement. Since the `console.log` executes after this, it will not execute until that loop has finished.

That's why you are seeing a difference.